# Redirecting to different Views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a couple of HTML files and I want to include them in my MVC project.
I want to get the result as follows:

```
www.Test.com/Products/

www.Test.com/Products/Drinking/
www.Test.com/Products/Drinking/Product1
www.Test.com/Products/Drinking/Product2
www.Test.com/Products/Drinking/Product3


www.Test.com/Products/Cleaning/
www.Test.com/Products/Cleaning/Product1
www.Test.com/Products/Cleaning/Product2
www.Test.com/Products/Cleaning/Product3

www.Test.com/Products/SkinCare/
www.Test.com/Products/SkinCare/Product1
www.Test.com/Products/SkinCare/Product2
www.Test.com/Products/SkinCare/Product3
```

What is the best way to create my controller and how to put my files in nested views?
or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products could be your controller 
Drinking, Cleaning, and SkinCare could be actions
with product1 product2 product3 being the id passed to the action.

Then return which ever view you want based on the productId. Or create a strongly typed view based on a class called Product and Pass the product object to the view.

```
   public class ProductsController : Contoller
   {
       public ActionResult Cleaning(string id)
       {
            Product p = new Product();
            //create the product based on the id

           return view(p);

        }

    }
```

or return a specific view name

```
return view("Product1");
```

or for a strongly typed view

```
return view("Product1",p);
```

Comment: but where should i copy my Product1.cshtml files

Comment: Views/Products/Drinking/Product1.cshtml ?

Answer (score 0):

The [ASP] framework itself should take care of the routing for you. Models, Controllers and Views should all follow a specific naming convention which should then result in the correct URLs.

Comment: I think he is using asp.net MVC based on tags

Comment: I just noticed :) - regardless, the ASP framework should follow the same principles...